# How to dynamic filter on Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can I make a dynamic filter on a Power BI chart?

I have a MONTH table and it contains these values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12. I do not want to display data for months that are bigger than the current month, MONTH(TODAY()).

I want something like this:

[image: Dynamic Filter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a measure instead to determine whether to show the particular month or not as follows:

```
Show = IF(FIRSTNONBLANK('Month'[Month], 13) <= MONTH(TODAY()), 1, 0)
```

And then you can add this measure to `Visual level filters` and set it equal to 1.

Results:

[image: measure]
[image: filter]